# Compare 2 tables in Polars and select a value based on that comparison

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a table like this in polars:

| arrival_time | Train |
| --- | --- |
| 08:40:10 | 112 |
| 19:31:26 | 134 |

An I have another table that defines the period of the day based on the hours:

| Time | Period |
| --- | --- |
| 08:00:00 | Early |
| 16:00:00 | Afternoon |

What I am trying to achieve is a Polars way to combine both tables and obtain in the first table the Period of the day as a new column:

| arrival_time | Train | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:40:10 | 112 | Early |
| 19:31:26 | 134 | Afternoon |

For now what I am doing is working entirely with dictionaries, zipping the 2 columns of my comparison table and computing the key of the minimium distance beetween the 2 time columns:

```
min(dict(zip( df.Period,df.Time)).items(), key=lambda x: abs(pl.col('arrival_time') - x[1]))[0])
```

But i am certainly sure that there's a better way to process in Polars.

Comment: Can you add the code to create your data next time in the question? That helps a lot when trying to answer the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Polars has `join_asof` which joins to the closest key `forward` or `backward` in time.

```py
from datetime import time

df_a = pl.DataFrame({
    "arrival_time": [time(8, 40, 10), time(19, 31, 26)],
    "train": [112, 134]
})

df_b = pl.DataFrame({
    "arrival_time": [time(8), time(16)],
    "period": ["early", "afternoon"]
    
})

print(df_a.join_asof(df_b, on="arrival_time"))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ arrival_time ┆ train ┆ period    │
│ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ time         ┆ i64   ┆ str       │
╞══════════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 08:40:10     ┆ 112   ┆ early     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19:31:26     ┆ 134   ┆ afternoon │
└──────────────┴───────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Buildling on @ritchie46 answer, if you need to find the **closest** value, you can apply `join_asof` in both the forward and backward direction, and choose the result that is closest.

For example, if we start with this data:

```py
df_a = pl.DataFrame(
    {"arrival_time": [time(8, 40, 10), time(8, 59, 0), time(
        19, 31, 26)], "train": [112, 113, 134]}
)
df_b = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "arrival_time": [
            time(8),
            time(8, 30, 0),
            time(9),
            time(16),
            time(16, 30, 0),
            time(17),
        ],
        "period": [
            "early morning",
            "mid-morning",
            "late morning",
            "early afternoon",
            "mid afternoon",
            "late afternoon",
        ],
    }
)
df_a
df_b
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────────┬───────┐
│ arrival_time ┆ train │
│ ---          ┆ ---   │
│ time         ┆ i64   │
╞══════════════╪═══════╡
│ 08:40:10     ┆ 112   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 08:59:00     ┆ 113   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19:31:26     ┆ 134   │
└──────────────┴───────┘
>>> df_b
shape: (6, 2)
┌──────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ arrival_time ┆ period          │
│ ---          ┆ ---             │
│ time         ┆ str             │
╞══════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 08:00:00     ┆ early morning   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 08:30:00     ┆ mid-morning     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 09:00:00     ┆ late morning    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16:00:00     ┆ early afternoon │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16:30:00     ┆ mid afternoon   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17:00:00     ┆ late afternoon  │
└──────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

We see that train `113` arrives closer to `late morning` than to `mid-morning`.  If you need to capture that, you can join with both `backward` and `forward`, and then choose which is closest:

```py
(
    df_a
    .join_asof(df_b.with_column(pl.col('arrival_time').alias('early_time')), on="arrival_time", strategy="backward", suffix="_early")
    .join_asof(df_b.with_column(pl.col('arrival_time').alias('late_time')), on="arrival_time", strategy="forward", suffix="_late")
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('early_time').is_null())
        .then(pl.col('period_late'))
        .when(pl.col('late_time').is_null())
        .then(pl.col('period'))
        .when((pl.col('arrival_time').cast(pl.Datetime) - pl.col('early_time').cast(pl.Datetime)) <
              (pl.col('late_time').cast(pl.Datetime) - pl.col('arrival_time').cast(pl.Datetime)))
        .then(pl.col('period'))
        .otherwise(pl.col('period_late'))
        .alias('closest')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌──────────────┬───────┬────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┬────────────────┐
│ arrival_time ┆ train ┆ period         ┆ early_time ┆ period_late  ┆ late_time ┆ closest        │
│ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---            ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---            │
│ time         ┆ i64   ┆ str            ┆ time       ┆ str          ┆ time      ┆ str            │
╞══════════════╪═══════╪════════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪════════════════╡
│ 08:40:10     ┆ 112   ┆ mid-morning    ┆ 08:30:00   ┆ late morning ┆ 09:00:00  ┆ mid-morning    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 08:59:00     ┆ 113   ┆ mid-morning    ┆ 08:30:00   ┆ late morning ┆ 09:00:00  ┆ late morning   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19:31:26     ┆ 134   ┆ late afternoon ┆ 17:00:00   ┆ null         ┆ null      ┆ late afternoon │
└──────────────┴───────┴────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```

Note that in the `when/then/otherwise` I've chosen to explicitly handle the case where a train arrives before the first period or after the last period.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks,  just a thought , when it is btw the first and the last  i get this:

arrival_time   period        early_time p_late   late_time   closest
07:18:22 "mid night" 23:30:00   null null      "mid night"
07:19:55 "mid night" 23:30:00   null null      "mid night"
07:25:51 "mid night" 23:30:00   null null      "mid night"

is there a way to approach this? thank youy anyway for the answer, love polars

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate your results..  Are your DataFrames sorted by arrival_time? From the documentation: "Both DataFrames must be sorted by the asof_join key."  If they are not sorted, you can get strange results.